# I have issue in adding WCF service reference,

Tags: c#, wcf, service, client, endpoint

I add a console application project to my solution which has some services. And then "Add Service reference" when I select `MyService`, then I get this error:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://localhost/prj/Services/MyService.svc/$metadata'. The request
>   failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request. Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost/prj/Services/MyService.svc'. Content Type
>   application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   http://localhost/prj/Services/MyService.svc.  The client and service
>   bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an error: (415)
>   Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.. If the service is defined in the current
>   solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference
>   again.

I tried to to change the endpoint in config file to the following element:

```
<endpoint 
    address="http://localhost:52644/Services/MyService.svc" 
    binding="mexHttpBinding" 
    contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

But I still get the same issue.

Also when I put my service URL in the browser, I get this:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.

My service config has the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None"/>

          <!-- Service Extensions -->
          <ServiceSecurityConfig/>
          <MessageLoggingConfig/>
          <ErrorLoggingConfig/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="ServiceSecurityConfig" type="MyService.Security.ServiceSecurityConfig, MyService"/>
        <add name="MessageLoggingConfig" type="MyService.Logging.MessageLoggingConfig, MyService"/>
        <add name="ErrorLoggingConfig" type="MyService.Logging.ErrorLoggingConfig, MyService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>-->
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Would be great if somebody can help.

Thanks

Comment: The first error suggests that the bindings setup in your service and client configs do not match.  I see that you have supplied the endpoint element for the client config.  What does the service config's binding look like? Is it also "mexHttpBinding"?

Comment: @yeah-buddy _"service and client configs do not match"_ - well the client config won't exist yet because he is in the middle of **Add Service Reference...***.   Besides, you don't specify a MEX client `<endpoint>` in client config

Comment: Please post your entire `<system.serviceModel>` from your config file thanks

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples, config or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: The service binding is "basicHttpBinding" but the issue is when I use basicHttpBinding in Client it throw that error, should I change service binding to mexHttpBinding?